# Centreon not printing output from bash script

Tags: shell, nagios

I have a bash script that do checks and show result correctly in local server
but when using graphic web of Centreon the message is empty

I use echo as output of function called from main

Comment: The bug is in line 42 of your bash script. (Sorry, my answer can't get more precise than your question).

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, the problem it is when i run script in Nagios-Centreon
i have this outpout NRPE: Unable to read output in OS AIX
the code is large, i resolve it by changing ***#!/bin/ksh*** instead of
***#!/bin/bash***
Basically the problem is because of special caracters in script shell.

[https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nrpe-nrpe-unable-to-read-output-620.html#:~:text=This%20error%20implies%20that%20NRPE,when%20running%20the%20remote%20plugin%20](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nrpe-nrpe-unable-to-read-output-620.html#:%7E:text=This%20error%20implies%20that%20NRPE,when%20running%20the%20remote%20plugin%20).